# How to restrict user to access particular ec2 machines?

Tags: amazon-web-services

With this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restrict-ec2-iam/#), I can restrict user only to poweron/off a machine and terminate option is removed.

But, I want to restrict user to access only few machines assigned to the user and not show other machines.

With only the Owner or any custom tag we can filter.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how far you want to *restrict* that access and it will depend on how you define the IAM policy / role that you assign to the user.

For example, you can't prevent the user from seeing instances that don't match their custom tag filter because the DescribeInstances action doesn't accept Condition Keys. On the other hand, RunInstances does allow for aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey} condition keys to be applied, same for StartInstances and StopInstances.

You can have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html for the full list of actions and condition keys that apply.